# python package useful for analyzing user inputted 2D vector graphics

Tags: python, vector-graphics

I've seen many python packages that can draw vectors and pictures with code(like PyX or cairo), but I'm looking for something that is useful for the reverse process, where you have a user draw a picture with the mouse and can use that picture as input to your program. for example, if a user draws a straight line on a canvas, I'd like to be able to access the start and end points of that line. Any suggestions for how one might accomplish this task? thanks in advance